# Fourier transform of $(1 + \mathrm{i} a \ \mathrm{sign} ( t))^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider the function defined over $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{i} \  a  \ \mathrm{sign} (t)}$$
with $a \neq 0$ and $\mathrm{sign}(t) = 1$ if $t \geq 0$, $(-1)$ otherwise. This function can be seen as a tempered distribution, so that its Fourier transform $F = \mathcal{F} \{f\} \in \mathcal{S}'$ is well-defined.

**Question:** Is there a known closed form for $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be derived from the Fourier transform of the step function. We obtain
$$\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega) =- \frac{2 a}{1+a^2} \mathcal{P} \left(\frac1{\omega}\right) + \frac{2\pi}{1+a^2} \delta(\omega); $$
here, $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the principal value and I have defined the Fourier transform as $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega) = \int\!dt f(t) e^{-i\omega t}$.

Comment: I am not sure to follow. The Fourier transform of $1 + \mathrm{i} a \mathrm{sign} (t)$ is $\delta(\omega) + \mathrm{i} a \mathcal{P}\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)$ (which looks like your result, up to the constants). Here, I am considering the inverse of this function. Can you explain how do you get your formula. 

PS. As pointed out by Rodrigo de Azevedo, the title was not in line with the question.

Comment: Yes, constants do matter! The Fourier transform of the step function $u(t)$ is given by $\pi \delta(\omega) + i \mathcal{P} \omega^{-1}$. Just compose your function as a sum $f_1 + f_2$ of two (constant) functions defined on $t>0$ and $t<0$. The use the knowledge of the Fourier transform of a step function to obtain the result (the Fourier transform is linear of course).

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.